Generating multi-page pdf with Itext Html2Pdf
I am using iText in C# to convert HTML to a PDF. When converting the HTML to a PDF it works fine if the HTML content is within 1 page but if the content is greater than 1 page, the code doesn't work.
see the code below of iText.
public int PDFReport(string baseuri, string html, string destination)
{
  try
  {
      ConverterProperties prop = new ConverterProperties();
      prop.SetBaseUri(baseuri);


      HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create), prop);
      return 1;
  }
  catch
  {
      return 0;
  }
}

It give me the following exception and does not generate the PDF if I continue.

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at line HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, pdfDoc, prop);

i have tried break-after; I've tried to break it through CSS but this is not working either, I read that i need to use Event handler or something.

It might be related to your html can you provide the html you are using, or a reproducible sample?
Also which iText and pdf Version are you using

you can find the html here: https://github.com/fahadshaikh876/salesreporthtml/blob/main/SO_Html
iText7 -- 7.2.0
itext7.pdfhtml  -- 4.0.0

This sounds like a missing or incorrect dependency of iText.
Without knowing your exact environment, target framework and installed dependencies, it's impossible to isolate the problem further, but I can tell you that this code works correctly with the HTML provided (and an arbitrary baseUrl) when run as a C# Console Application targeting .NET 8.0 with the following four NuGet packages installed (and no others):

itext
itext.commons
itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter
itext7.pdfhtml

Several 'first chance' exceptions are thrown and handled/swallowed by iText during the parsing/conversion process. If your exception settings are incorrect, it's possible your application is incorrectly failing immediately instead of allowing the application to continue as normal.
The complete (working) code sample, including using declarations, is:
using iText;
using iText.Html2pdf;

var html = File.ReadAllText("c:\\temp\\Html.txt");
var destination = "c:\\temp\\Html2.txt";

try
{
    ConverterProperties prop = new ConverterProperties();
    prop.SetBaseUri("http://example.com");

    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create), prop);
    return 1;
}
catch
{
    return 0;
}

One thing you could try, if you haven't already, is saving the HTML to a local file before parsing, as in this code sample.

the page has tr and td where it could lead other page so its not working
any other way?
